# Cannot return the result to the browser with result.send?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, express

I am successful at querying a MS-SQL server, but cannot get to display the result in the browser.

```js
var express = require('express');
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
var app = express();

const main = async() => {
  const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    server: "example.com",
    database: "example",
    options: {
      trustedConnection: true
    }
  });

  await pool.connect();

  const request = new sql.Request(pool);
  const query0 = 'select getdate()' // Lets keep it simple..
  const result = await request.query(query0);

  //console.dir(result);
  //console.log(result.recordsets[0])
  return result.recordsets[0]
};

app.get('/', function(res, req) {
  var a = main()
  a.then(function(r) {
    console.log(r[0])
    res.send(r[0])
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('fetch error', err)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('really bad:', error)
  })
})
var server = app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('Server is running.....');
});
```

I get the date back but I am getting the following error:

> Server is running.....
>   { '': { 2018-07-17T11:30:02.060Z nanosecondsDelta: 0 } }
>   really bad: TypeError: res.write is not a function
>       at C:\node2mssql2\node2mssql\app0.js:34:13

Any ideas what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: The error message says `res.write`, but the posted code has `res.send`. What's actually on line 34 of `app0.js`?

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

`app.get('/',function(res,req){`

to 

`app.get('/',function(req,res){`

and maybe add `status(200)` to res.`status(200)`.send(r[0])

by the way, make sure you return a response on every situation (on error, on success).

Comment: Thank so much. This flies.

Comment: great! now, would you mind accepting this as the answer?